# What is the probability that in a group of n people chosen at random, there are at least two born in the same month of the year?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, birthday

So I'm working on a probability problem:

> In Exercise 19 assume it is equally
>   likely that a person is born in any given month of the year.
>
> 19. b) What is the probability that in a group of $n$ people chosen at random, there are at least two born in the same month of the year?

I know that the probability of two people being born in the same month is $1/12$ (from part a of this problem) and that the pigeonhole principle shows that some $n≥12$ will guarantee that two people within the group were born within the same month.

I don't know what to do with this information though, especially when looking at the book answer: $1 − 11/12 · 10/12 ··· (13−n)/12$. It doesn't make sense to me that a group ($n$) containing only 1 person with this formula would have a 100% chance of being born in the same month as someone else in the group. You need two people to compare birth months, so how can this be right? I  thought that after 12 people, you'd be guaranteed to find two people with matching birth months. If I were to make a formula, it would look more like: $(n-1)·(1/12)$

Comment: Look up "the birthday problem" or "the birthday paradox" and replace $365$ by $12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion may be related to the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product)

Your expression could have started $1 - \frac{12}{12}\frac{11}{12}\cdots\frac{13-n}{12}$.

Then with $n=1$ it would give a probability of $1 - \frac{12}{12}=0$ that at least two born in the same month of the year, which is the obvious result with only one person

For other values of $n$ you would get the following probabilities that at least two born in the same month of the year, which is decidedly non-linear.  As with the classic [birthday or collision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), the probability exceeds $\frac12$ well before you have half as many individuals as there possible birthdays

```
 n      Prob
 1      0
 2      0.08333
 3      0.23611
 4      0.42708
 5      0.61806
 6      0.77720
 7      0.88860
 8      0.95358
 9      0.98453
10      0.99613
11      0.99936
12      0.99995
13+     1
```